# How do I backup my C++ Builder component installation?

Tags: components, c++builder

I finally have my C++ Builder 2010 installation the way I want it, with all my components upgraded and installed. (touch wood)

I have been working with C++builder since version 1 and I know from countless previous traumatic experiences that this state of affairs could change in an instant. I would like to backup the installation and component set.

Is there a way to do this? A tool perhaps? A menu command that I have maybe missed all these years? I don't want to have to reinstall all the components from the bpl source again.

I make nightly backup images of my entire drive, I would like to do this for c++builder only if possible.

If it's a matter of simply copying files, which files would I need to copy? Are there entries in the registry that would need to be restored?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts and suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HKCU\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\ registry section contains the "known packages" subtree that contains which components you have installed. reg export/import should save you some trouble.

You'll also want to backup/restore the actual files referenced there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I used C++ Builder, but I will make two suggestions...

1) run regedit and looks for "builder". You will probably find a hive like hk_local_machine/software/codegear or such. Export that and you can import it later

2) have a look at GExperts - is they don't have the exact solution, they still have some pretty useful (and free) tools

Comment: gexperts doesn't do that from what I can tell, but it is awesome, thanks for the tip

Comment: Then I guess it's registry edit and export the relevant hive (and, yes, I do like Gexperts)